# Using Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted() with Thread.sleep()

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, interrupt, interrupted-exception

I have a thread that calls a work() method which is a simple while(true)-loop as below;

```
public void work() throws InterruptedException {
    while (true) {
        // PART A
        if (Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
            System.out.println("....run()::work::PART A::isInterrupted():" + Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted());
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        }

        // Is it possible to make the below code executable at runtime when thread is interrupted?
        // PART B
        if (Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
            System.out.println("....run()::work::PART B::isInterrupted():" + Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted());
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        }
    }
}
```

I run this thread instance and interrupt the thread from the main after a period of time with Thread.sleep() method. As I change the delay, I expect to hit the commented part when the thread is interrupted from the main thread but I only see the output below;

```
....run()::Work::starting
.main()::interrupting thread t
.main()::leaving
....run()::work::PART A::isInterrupted():true
....run()::Work::ERROR::INTERRUPTED
```

My simple question is this, **is it possible to execute the second part (Part B) of the work() method, or if not, why?**

The complete demo is as below;

```
public class GeneralInterrupt implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        try {
            System.out.println("....run()::Work::starting");
            work();
            System.out.println("....run()::Work::ended");
        } catch (InterruptedException x) {
            System.out.println("....run()::Work::ERROR::INTERRUPTED");
            return;
        }
        System.out.println("....run()::Work::leaving normally");
    }

    public void work() throws InterruptedException {
        while (true) {
            // PART A
            if (Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                System.out.println("....run()::work::PART A::isInterrupted():" + Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted());
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            }

            // Is it possible to make the below code executable at runtime when thread is interrupted?
            // PART B
            if (Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                System.out.println("....run()::work::PART B::isInterrupted():" + Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted());
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread t = new Thread(new GeneralInterrupt());
        t.start();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        } catch (InterruptedException x) {
        }
        System.out.println(".main()::interrupting thread t");
        t.interrupt();
        System.out.println(".main()::leaving");
    }
}
```

Please also notify that, if the "Thread.sleep(2000)" lines are both removed from the A and B part, then the output is

```
....run()::work::PART B::isInterrupted():false
....run()::work::PART B::isInterrupted():false
....run()::work::PART B::isInterrupted():false
....run()::work::PART B::isInterrupted():false
....run()::work::PART A::isInterrupted():true
....run()::work::PART A::isInterrupted():true
....run()::work::PART A::isInterrupted():true
....run()::work::PART A::isInterrupted():true
....run()::work::PART A::isInterrupted():true
```

Can anybody explain why Thread.sleep() method is behaving in such a way inside the work() method.

Comment: What @Thomas is trying to tell you is that, when an interrupt happens, you can't control whether it will happen in code that you wrote, or in library code that your code calls.  If it happens in library code, then what guarantee do you have that the library will handle the interrupt they way you wish it to be handled?  A _well designed_ library routine will stop whatever it is doing and re-throw the interrupt, leaving it up to your program what to do next.  A less well designed library might assume that interrupt == shut-down, and it might leave things in a bad state.

Answer (score 1):

As per [Oracle Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interrupt.html), interrupting a thread is a signal to the thread to end its current work and do something else (like terminating):

> An interrupt is an indication to a thread that it should stop what it is doing and do something else. It's up to the programmer to decide exactly how a thread responds to an interrupt, but it is very common for the thread to terminate. This is the usage emphasized in this lesson.

Thus it should generally be possible to continue after an interrupt.

As per [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt--) on interrupts, it depends on where the thread is interrupted:

> If this thread is blocked in an invocation of the wait(), wait(long), or wait(long, int) methods of the Object class, or of the join(), join(long), join(long, int), **sleep(long)**, or sleep(long, int), methods of this class, then its *interrupt status will be cleared* and it will receive an *InterruptedException*. (emphasis added by me)

That's why you get the exception when using `sleep(2000)`.

Answer (score 0):

When you interrupt the thread and it is in the `sleep` method, `sleep` will throw an `InterruptedException`. You do not handle this exception. It is propagated to your `run` method and your `while` loop exits.

You need to surround your `sleep` with a try/catch and catch `InterruptedException`. You must also be sure to call `Thread.currentThread().interrupt()` after catching it, if you want `isInterrupted()` to return true after the exception, since the exception will reset the interrupt flag. Like this:

```
     if (Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
         System.out.println("....run()::work::PART A::isInterrupted():" 
             + Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted());
         try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

`Thread.isInterrupted()` [doesn't clear the interrupted status of the thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#isInterrupted--). So when you call `sleep()`, an `InterruptedException` is thrown. You need to call `Thread.interrupted()` instead of `Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()`.

However that will mean that Part B will only execute if an interrupt occurred during the sleep after Part A, which appears to be what you want. If you need Part B to run whenever Part A runs, put it into the same block instead of after a second test.